# How can I locate who took my money?

Tags: coinbase.com

Need help to try locate where my bitcoin went to. Was given a company wallet address to send my money to. I realise now I was scammed. Would you be able to help me locate exchange that my €5700 went to?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that anyone can help.

Anyone wanting to avoid being traced is likely to follow best-practise: Bitcoin addresses are only used once. transfers of money can be forwarded to other addresses owned by the scammer and can be forwarded through [bitcoin mixers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_tumbler) which make it pretty much impossible to follow where the money went.

You can type the address into a [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) but this doesn't help identify the person who controls that address.

As you know, Bitcoin is intended to be fairly anonymous. Just as it can be very hard to find out the names of all the people who have handled a $5 bill before or after you, even if you know the serial number printed on it. This is by design, for privacy.

If you are the victim of fraud, you should report it to your local police. Even if they cannot help you recover your money it helps them and politicians to be aware of the level of such crime and helps them decide whether more resources are needed.

---

Other web-pages that may be of interest (this is not an endorsement)

- [Where to report Bitcoin Scams](https://bitcoinwhoswho.com/blog/2018/04/21/where-to-report-bitcoin-scams/)

---

Update:

Oops, I see you asked the same question last year and got a good answer, voting to close as duplicate.